# I got some problem on Iot hub and corporate network's proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, proxy, .net-core, azure-iot-hub

I tried to connect to IOT Hub with Asp.net core but I could not to get devices from IOT hub. When i tried to connect internet directly I can get devices from IOT hub. So i think the reason might be corporate network's proxy. Could you please consider again and let me know if you know anything. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add proxy setting explicitly to the application.

For **Registry Manager** try the following code:

```
using System.Net;
// s_proxyServerAddress= ...
// s_connectionString = ...
HttpTransportSettings customTransportSettings = new HttpTransportSettings();
customTransportSettings.Proxy = new WebProxy(s_proxyServerAddress);

JobClient jobClient = JobClient.CreateFromConnectionString(s_connectionString, customTransportSettings);
RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(s_connectionString, customTransportSettings);
```

More detailed info is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/pull/569).

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried it but Exceptions.IotHubCommunicationException is still alert  .

Comment: @Sunday Thanks for the confirmation. You can [open an issue at C# SDK repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues) and provide what you have tried and the link points to the proxy setting sample.

Comment: @Sunday The issue solved? If not, another direction is to check the proxy is working or not. For HTTP, make sure port 443 inbounds is allowed.